# How to insert text into file in specific place?

Tags: php

My file looks like this. I need to append some new array keys inside this via `file_put_contents`.

```
<?php
    $translation = array(
        'Wyposażenie' => 'Equipment',
    );
?>
```

I don't know how to do this. Only thing I know is that i have to use `file_put_contents($file, "'test' => 'new value',", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);` but it will put new informations at the end of file. How to append my new informations right after last array key. To get something this:

```
<?php
    $translation = array(
        'Wyposażenie' => 'Equipment',
        'test' => 'new value',
    );
?>
```

Comment: That's not an array. That's *text*. Adding content to an array is easy. Putting it in random text is not.

Comment: Also, maybe use `json_encode`.  But aside from that modify the array and `var_export`.

Comment: _@John Conde_ You are trying to tell me that it's impossible ? :) What about get this into a string, remove: `); ?>` from the end, then append data to string, and then again add `); ?>` and finally save ?

Comment: Why not try it and see? Although there are *much* better ways to do this. This is just painful to do.

Comment: looks like a one of job that should be handled faster by hand

Comment: I just ran into this idea. So what solution would be best?

Comment: find the string `'Wyposażenie' => 'Equipment',` replace with the string `'Wyposażenie' => 'Equipment',
        'test' => 'new value',`

Comment: @Dagon Not exactly. I have to generate a lot of informations to translate for Translators. It will generate something about 1000 lines of code. I don't wan't to push that into this file manually.

Comment: well if you keep changing the question ....

Comment: Naah. I've already finished this task. Finnally I wrote this on myself and forgot about this thread. Tommorrow I will publish my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrote this my self. Here is my code:

```
public static function l($string)
{       
    $string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string));

    if($_SESSION['lang']=='default')
    {       
        return $string;
    }
    else
    {
        $file = 'translations/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php';

        if (file_exists($file))
        {
            require($file);

            $search = array_key_exists($string, $translation);

            if($search && $translation[$string] != ' ')
            {
                # ZNALAZŁ TŁUMACZENIE
                return $translation[$string];
            }
            else
            {
                if(!$search)
                {
                    # NIE ZNALAZŁ TŁUMACZENIA
                    $translation[$string] = ' '; 

                    $serialized = "<?php\n\$translation = array( \n\n\n";
                    while ($array = current($translation)) {

                        if(key($translation))
                        {
                            $serialized .= "'".key($translation)."'\n=>\n'".current($translation)."',\n\n\n";
                        }

                        next($translation);
                    }
                    $serialized .= ");\n?>";

                    file_put_contents($file, $serialized);
                }
                if($translation[$string] == ' ')
                {
                    # ZNALAZŁ PUSTE TŁUMACZENIE
                }

                return $string;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return $string;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned in comments, this can be done using json in better way but just for this case here is how you can do it:

```
<?php
$read = file_get_contents("i.txt");

$delete = strrpos($read,");",-1);

$read = substr($read,0,$delete);

$new_value = "'test' => 'new value',";

$read .= "\r\n\$new_value \r\n);\r\n ?>";

file_put_contents('i.txt',$read);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was bored.  This will not overwrite keys that exist.  To overwrite, reverse the arrays in the `array_merge()`:

```
function add_to_trans($file, $array) {
    include($file);
    $result = array_merge($translation, $array);
    file_put_contents($file, '$translation = ' . var_export($result, true));
}

$new_trans = array('test' => 'new value');
add_to_trans('path/to/file.php', $new_trans);
```

But you should rethink this and save a `json_encode()` array in the file and read it back out.